# how to join two tables using group by order by and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

**tblXYZ**

```
patId | Name |  DOB
---------------------------
 1    | xyz  |  10-05-1986
 2    | abc  |   12-06-01978
 3    | lmn  |   12-04-1975
```

**tblABC**

```
apptId | patId | status   | otherinfo
-------------------------------------
  1    |  1    |   single | jmdfh
  2    |  1    |   sds    | dfdf  
  3    |  2    |   fdf    | sdwed  
  4    |  2    |   fdf    | sdwed
```

I want join these two table to get result as:

**result**

```
patId | apptId | Name   |  DOB
--------------------------------
  1   |   2    | single |  jmdfh
  2   |   4    |  sds   |  dfdf  
  3   |  null  |  fdf   |  sdwed
```

`apptId` should be the last entered value from `tblABC`

Comment: Shouldn't your first result be either `1 1 single jmdfh` or `1 2 sds dfdf`?

Comment: Shouldn't the second result be `2 4 fdf sdwed` and the last one `3 null null null`?

Comment: With the result query, did you want the 3rd and 4th columns to be `status` and `otherinfo`? I'm a little confused, because the data doesn't match the names.

Comment: In addition to what others have said above about patId 1, how should the result for patId 3 be derived?

Comment: Your result looks completely wrong. How can DOB be jmdfhl. The third row should either be 3, null, null, null or 3, null, lmn, 12-04-1975. Please update your question so it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
select patId, apptId, Name, DOB
join -- or left join if you want patId that doesn't have match in the second table
(
  select patId AS patIdBis, max(apptId) AS apptId 
  from tblABC group by patId
)
on patId = patIdBis
order by patId;
```

Comment: This query will not work if one needs to project anything from tblABC other than apptId.

Comment: But it answers his question. If the question was different, the answer would have been different as well

Comment: This appears to be the answer to the question, though the question is so unclear it really is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

If by "last entered" you mean largest apptId, then the following query will do what you want.

```sql
SELECT tblXYZ.patId, tblABC.apptId, tblXYZ.name, tblXYZ.DOB
FROM tblXYZ
     LEFT JOIN
     (
         (SELECT patId, MAX(apptId) mx FROM tblABC GROUP BY patId) maxes
         INNER JOIN tblABC
         ON maxes.patId = tblABC.patId AND maxes.mx = tblABC.apptId
     ) ON tblXYZ.patId = tblABC.patId;
```

UPDATE: Valentin Clement's query is shorter and is better if you only need the apptId from the tblABC. If you need any other data from the tblABC, then you need to use the query from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get your result

```
SELECT x.patid, a.apptid, x.name, x.dob 
FROM tblxyz x INNER JOIN tblabc a ON 
x.patid=a.patid
```

```
patid apptid  name  DOB
1     1       xyz   1986-10-05 00:00:00.000
1     2       xyz   1986-10-05 00:00:00.000
2     3       abc   1978-12-06 00:00:00.000
2     4       abc   1978-12-06 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Suggest you edit you post so that appears in a code block. That is hard to read, but appears to be lacking any max also.